# Why is such an expression needed in this C program

Tags: c

I am a beginner and this piece of code (which seems to be very simple) causes me problems. This is function of a program(an example of the book) that simply select five random cards.

```
void shuffle( aDeck * thisDeck )
{
   int x;
   int iRnd;
   int found = 0;

   system("clear");

   printf("\nYour five cards are: \n\n");

   while ( found < 5 ) {

      iRnd = rand() % 52;

      if ( thisDeck[iRnd].used == 'n' ) {

         switch (thisDeck[iRnd].value) {

            case 12:
               printf("Ace of %s\n", thisDeck[iRnd].type);
               break;

            case 11:
               printf("King of %s\n", thisDeck[iRnd].type);
               break;

            case 10:
               printf("Queen of %s\n", thisDeck[iRnd].type);
               break;

            case 9:
               printf("Jack of %s\n", thisDeck[iRnd].type);
               break;

            default:
               printf("%d of ", thisDeck[iRnd].value + 2);
               printf("%s\n", thisDeck[iRnd].type);
               break;

         } // end switch

         thisDeck[iRnd].used = 'y';

         found = found + 1;

      } //end if

   } // end while loop

} //end shuffle
```

What i do not understand is the expression

> found = found + 1;

Why if I change the value of the constant strange things happens ( like for 4 the output give 2 cards ) ?

I am very grateful for your time !

Comment: constant? what constant? found is a variable, and you add one to it. What do you mean by 'strange things'?

Comment: Note that it would often be clearer to use a `for` loop: `for (found = 0; found < 5; found++)` — also using an increment in place of `found = found + 1;` or the equivalent `found += 1;`. This puts all the loop control information on a single line. In this context, though, the increment is only required when the randomly chosen card has not previously been selected. You could use an inner loop to find an unused card: `for (iRnd = rand() % 52; thisDeck[iRnd].used != 'n'; iRnd = rand() % 52) ;`. Note that your code may execute the loop more than five times if a previously used card is selected.

Answer (score 2):

The function has to select five cards. Variable `found` is used like a counter of selected cards. If a card was selected the counter that is variable `found` is increased

```
found = found + 1;
```

The selection continues until `found` is equal to 5 as it is required.

Initially `found` is set to 0

```
int found = 0;
```

because no card is selected yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
found = found + 1;
```

counts the cycles of the cards drawn.

If you increase it by 4, the while would only cycle twice:

the first for found == zero

the second for found == 4

Also, if I may: quite a few details in the code may be improved.

Example1: get rid of the `switch`. Include the description of the card as an attribute of the structure for the card, alongside `.value` and `.type`. That way you just need to print it out.

Example2: make the `.used` flag an `int` (holding nonzero if used, zero if not).

Answer (score 0):

- `found` is a counter to count select times and make your card select logic continue

  ```
  int found = 0;
  while(found < 5){ //found = 0,1,2,3,4, totally 5 cards will be selected
  ...
  //pick up one card
  ...
  found = found + 1; //to count pick up times and make while loop continue
  }
  ```
- to change `found` will change selected card num(`5 - initial_value_of_ found`)

  ```
  int found = 4; // will select "5-4" cards
  while(found < 5){ //found = 4, totally 1 cards will be selected
  ...
  //pick up one card
  ...
  found = found + 1; //to make while loop continue
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Take out stuff from the code unrelated to your question and you get

```
void shuffle( aDeck * thisDeck )
{
     int found = 0;

     while ( found < 5 )
     {
          //  pick a card, print out what has been picked, and register it as used

      found = found + 1;
      } // end while loop

} //end shuffle
```

So the body of the while loop will be executed `5` times.   In this case, that means picking five cards.   The value of `found` controls that:  for the first card, `found` will be `0`, the second `1`, ..... and the fifth `4`.

Changing the expression to something else will potentially change the number of cards picked.   It is probably easier to change the `while` condition though.

So changing to `found = found + 4` will change the number of iterations.   First iteration it will be `0`, second `4`, third `8`.   Eight is not less than five, so the result of the change is only picking two cards.

Answer (score 0):

The code is looking for 5 cards. Found variable works as a counter.. When you find a card you add one to the previous muber of found cards. This way, when founs reaches 5, you'll know you've find 5 cards